# Order in Venn diagram of four datasets VennDiagram

Tags: r, venn-diagram

I am trying to plot a venn diagram with four datasets using the R package VennDiagram, but I have problems to get the datasets in the correct order (from left to right) that I want. Any suggestions for how to manage the order?

---

What I have tried

I have four vectors of length 1950,2517,3753 and 884. Calculating all the overlaps first, and then

```
draw.quad.venn(area1, area2, area3, area4, 
               n12, n13, n14, n23, n24, n34,
               n123, n124, n134, n234, n1234, 
               category = c("A","B","C","D"), 
               lwd = rep(0, 4), lty = rep("solid", 4), 
               cex=rep(1.8,15), 
               fill = c("mediumseagreen","pink","lightblue","coral"))
```

Comment: Display your sample data set and what have you tried till now

Comment: I have four vectors of length 1950,2517,3753 and 884. Calculating all the overlaps first, and then

Comment: draw.quad.venn(area1, area2, area3, area4, n12, n13, n14,
n23, n24, n34, n123, n124, n134,
n234, n1234,
category = c("A","B","C","D"),
lwd = rep(0, 4), 
lty = rep("solid", 4), 
cex=rep(1.8,15),
fill = c("mediumseagreen","pink","lightblue","coral"))

Comment: Why dont you use the main function `venn.diagram` - which will calculate the interactions for you. So assuming your vectors start at one.. `p <- venn.diagram(list(a1=1:1950, a2=1:2517, a3=1:3753, a4=1:884), filename = NULL) ;grid.draw(p)`

Comment: That workd of course but it didn't solve my problem, the order is still the same.

Answer (score -1):

Change the order of datasets in the code:
category = c("A","B","C","D") - the first dataset (in this case "A" constitutes the left side of the venn diagram, the second dataset (in this case B) constitutes the right border of the venn diagram while C and D are in the middle between A and B. To have the datasets in alphabetic order in the diagram change the order to:                                                               category = c("A","D","B","C"). The same order should be also in command:                      venn.diagram(
x = list(A, D, B, C),